# Inactive list element style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In our WPF (.NET 4.5) application we would like to unify the look of standard list item selection. When active, the selected list/grid item is BLUE, but when the focus is lost, the color becomes GRAY. Is it possible to say somehow **globally**, that these color shouldn't change when focus is lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a recurrent one ! Put this

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF3399FF"/>
```

In your application or main window resources.

Another way to achieve that is to define a Style that will be implicitly applied to all of your ListBoxItem, TreeViewItem etc. and will override the ControlTemplate to change the way the trigger that changes background colors works.